# running a OS command from a macro

Tags: linux, libreoffice

I have a `scalc` sheet in Linux.

I need to write a macro that takes some argument from cell and calls a OS command with those arguments. I read a tutorial about how to create a libreoffice macro and how to call it in a cell.

I am not able to find which function to call WITHIN the macro to call my OS command.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Could this command be similar to VBA EXCEL for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [here](http://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Shell_Function_Runtime),

```
Shell("c:\windows\calc.exe",2)
```

full format is `Shell (Pathname As String[, Windowstyle As Integer][, Param As String][, bSync])`

so to run batch `q.bat` with `abc` as an argument:

```
Shell("q.bat",,"abc")
```

Comment: Great stuf!! Thanks a lot! AFG